# Config troubles consuming Web Service ASP.Net (Not WCF)

Tags: asp.net, winforms, web-services, soap

Well, i can't solve the following problem.

I have the next:
 * A Web Service development in C# + .Net Framework 3.5 + iBatis (VS2010) with some WebMethods.
 * The Web Service run on a local server, in IIS 5.1 (http://localhost/BookService/BookService.asmx).
 * An application WF+C# + .Net Framework 3.5 (VS2010) where the BO layer have a service reference to the Web Service.

The app.config generated by Service Reference is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>´
<configuration>
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BookServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
          maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
              maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://10.0.2.15/BookService/BooksService.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BookServiceSoap"
        contract="BookService.BookServiceSoap" name="BookServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I'm trying to connecting me to the web service making for example

```
BookService.BookServiceSoapClient query = new BookService.BookServiceSoapClient("BookServiceSoap","http://10.0.2.15/BookService/BookService.asmx");
```

or with out the endpointname and the url
    BookService.BookServiceSoapClient query = new BookService.BookServiceSoapClient();

But in execution time appears the following message

**Could not find endpoint element with name 'BookServiceSoap'
 and contract 'BookService.BookServiceSoap' in the ServiceModel
 client configuration section. This might be because no
 configuration file was found for your application, or because
 no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.**

Can somebody show me un right example to call for example the method HelloWorld.

Regards!